# How to configure Centos 7 firewallD to allow docker containers free access to the host's network ports?

Tags: centos, firewall, docker, firewalld

I have docker installed on CentOS 7 and I am running firewallD.

From inside my container, going to the host (default 172.17.42.1)

With firewall on

```
container# nc -v  172.17.42.1  4243
nc: connect to 172.17.42.1 port 4243 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

with firewall shutdown

```
container# nc -v  172.17.42.1  4243
Connection to 172.17.42.1 4243 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

I've read the docs on firewalld and I don't fully understand them.  Is there a way to simply allow everything in a docker container (I guess on the docker0 adapter) unrestricted access to the host?

Comment: I have found a really nice answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/994704/470071).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Maybe better than earlier answer;

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-port=4243/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: I believe the `add-port` is superfluous.  If `docker0` is marked trusted, that port will be let through anyway.

Comment: @MattHughes It worked for me without the `add-port`. You also need to **restart docker**.

Comment: Worked after firewalld restart, not docker

Comment: Docker manipulates iptables, and reloading firewalld will destroy those iptables rules. You have to restart the docker daemon after restarting or reloading firewalld.

Comment: Restarting docker is a must. Refer to https://success.docker.com/article/why-am-i-having-network-problems-after-firewalld-is-restarted

Comment: This induced `Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to program NAT chain: ZONE_CONFLICT: 'docker0' already bound to a zone` for me, even after a full reboot

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude same for me. Were you able to figure out what caused this?

Comment: @Hassan No; this whole thing is a nightmare to me. I've switched to an external firewall because of it. I think that we may just be screwed until [#461](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/461) is resolved.

Comment: If you are running Docker version 20.10.0 or higher with firewalld on your system with --iptables enabled, Docker automatically creates a firewalld zone called docker and inserts all the network interfaces it creates (for example, docker0) into the docker zone to allow seamless networking. https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: @Jay If you have a better answer, please write it as a new answer instead of editing an existing answer. If the community agrees with you, you will receive credit for it in the form of upvotes. You can explicitly add a reference to the answer you want to improve on in your answer, to point out possible problems with an existing answer.

Answer (score 14):

Theses commands did the trick:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-port=4243/tcp
```

Answer (score 7):

One reason the accepted solution works for some people but not for others lies in a design issue of firewalld. Firewalld only processes the first matching zone for any connections. It also processes zones based on IP address before zones based on interfaces. As long as any of your zones happens to include the IP addresses docker is using, the ACCEPT rule in the trusted zone will never get processed.

To verify this, you can look at the generated iptables rules unless you are using the nbt backend:

```
iptables -vnL | less
```

The solution is to use a firewalld direct rule instead of the trusted zone. Direct rules are always processed first. For example, for port 3306 (i.e., mysqld on the local host), you'd need this rule:

```
/bin/firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 10 -p tcp --dport 3306 -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

If you repeat the same command without the --permanent switch, firewalld will make the change on the fly for you, and you should not need to restart docker.

A second reason is that, depending on the version of docker and the networking you configured, traffic may not actually flow across the docker0 interface, but through a separate bridge interface. You can see that interface with the command

```
ip address show
```

You will have to repeat the direct-rule statement above with this bridge interface.

You can also specify your own network in docker. This post describes the process: https://serverfault.com/questions/885470/how-to-configure-firewall-on-user-defined-docker-bridge

The short version is that you specify the networks section in a docker-file, like this:

```
version: '3'
  .
  .
  .
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: mynetwork_name
```

You can also do this on the command line.

Comment: The --direct option is deprecated https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.direct

Comment: @trysten You are right. Also, iptables has been deprecated in favor of nftables. For CentOS 7, the answer still applies, though.

Answer (score 6):

I had problems with this as well; this did the trick for me:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
```

From: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/987686/no-network-connectivity-to-from-docker-ce-container-on-centos-8

Comment: Are you sure that’s enough? The answer to the question you linked to has a few more steps.

Comment: This fix worked for my case too

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, none of above solutions worked for me, one container was still not able to access another container.

Solution: **disable firewalld**

While I understand this is **really bad**, it actually works and the risks of disabled firewall can be mitigated my configuring `iptables` in the way you need.

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

Restarting docker is not needed, but just in case: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: By disabling the firewall temporarily I could determine that the firewall was the problem for sure.

Answer (score 2):

the following allowed docker to access the internet on CentOS 7 with firewalld

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 4 -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, but putting docker0 in the Trusted Zone didn't work since the traffic wasn't coming from docker0. I actually had two docker related connections.

```
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f1:89:6d:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0

6: br-2800c2ad17b6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:8a:7d:85:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-2800c2ad17b6
```

And inside the docker traffic was going over the bridge.

```
root@54b617929073:/# ip route show
default via 172.19.0.1 dev eth0 
172.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.27
```

Once I put br-2800c2ad17b6 in the trusted zone I was able to connect to the host.