# Docker inter-container communication with firewalld

Tags: docker, firewall, firewalld

I'm trying to install ansible awx `17.1.0` on a Fedora 33 Server.

The install process creates a few docker containers which need to communicate with each other.
With `firewalld` enabled, this does not work.

It works with `firewalld` disabled (but that's not the point).

So far, I've tried:

- [adding the `docker0` bridge to `trusted`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225845/112611) (by default it's in the `docker` zone - which doesn't work either):

  `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=docker0`
- [`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59511701/2519977)
- adding the ip ranges of the docker network to trusted:

  `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-source=10.17.0.0/16`

None of which seemed to do the trick. (In between I ran `firewall-cmd --reload` and `systemctl restart docker`.)

Docker seems to create another bridge `br-somecharacters` everytime I try to run the installer and increments the network `10.XX.0.0/16` by one everytime.

How do I properly enable inter-container traffic with `firewalld`?